# CoreLocation manager not updating locations

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, core-location

I was trying to implement a separate class for managing my location. I wanted to get my location whenever I click a button.

`gpsFilter.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface gpsFilter : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *gpsManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * longitude;
@end
```

`gpsFilter.m`.

```
#import "gpsFilter.h"

@implementation gpsFilter

- (id) init{
self = [super init];
if(self != nil){
    self.gpsManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.gpsManager.delegate = self;
    [self.gpsManager startUpdatingLocation];
    BOOL enable = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
    NSLog(@"%@", enable? @"Enabled" : @"Not Enabled");
}
return self;
}

- (void)gpsManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
if(currentLocation != nil){
    self.latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    self.longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}
}

- (void)gpsManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}
@end
```

I am using a separate class because I wanted to add smoothing filter in the future. I don't get any updates. The NSLog is never triggered. I think some variable is getting autoreleased, but I am not sure, which one.

The viewController code is as follows.

```
#import "gpstestViewController.h"

@interface gpstestViewController (){

}

@end

@implementation gpstestViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.location = [[gpsFilter alloc] init];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (IBAction)getloca:(id)sender {
self.latitudeLabel.text = [self.location latitude];
self.longitudeLabel.text = [self.location longitude];

}

- (IBAction)getLocation:(id)sender {
self.latitudeLabel.text = [self.location latitude];
self.longitudeLabel.text = [self.location longitude];

}
@end
```

I am sorry that I am dumping a lot of code, but I am a newbie to ios programming and I am not able to find what the problem is.

EDIT: The updateLocation delegate method is not being called at all.

Comment: Upvoted, because the cause was a bit hidden, You now have enough reputation to  upvote the correct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate methods must be named `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` and `locationManager:didFailWithError:`.

You cannot use custom method names like `gpsManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`.

Also note that `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` is deprecated as of iOS 6 and you should use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of your didUpdateToLocation is wrong:
This is my code:

```
/** Delegate method from the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol. */
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation    
{
  // here do 
}
```

Further set the `desiredAccuracy` to `CLLocationAccuracyBest`.

Comment: I am simulating it on Xcode. So that doesnt seem to the problem

Comment: I set it but it is not working. The update methods are not getting called at all. The NSLog messages in updateLocation are not getting printed.